# .htaccess file and ACL for a website

Tags: active-directory, acl

Does anyone know ho to restrict access to your own website using username and password. I know how to write .htaccess and places it the right place, but i am having problem with .htpasswd file. I did save the .thpasswd file outside the wwww directory and then I added username & password but when i tried to enter that username and password, it does not accept it. any help would be appreciated it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a full path to the .htpasswd file?

Also, does your .htaccess look like this?

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My private folder"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.passwd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: [Yes, I did. I don't know what's the problem exactly!!]

Comment: Did you generate the .htpasswd with the tool with the same name?

Comment: [What do you mean?. in the AuthUserFile, i entered the location of the .htpasswd]

Comment: But how did you create the .htpasswd file? It should be created with the htpasswd tool, for example `htpasswd -b .htpasswd username password` adds username to .htpasswd. You can try to put this `guest:6PTEFhrxg2idA` in .htpasswd and login as user _guest_ and password _guest_

Comment: Oh, yeh. I did that. I created a file named it .htpasswd outside www directory, then in AuthUserFile, i did mention the location of the .htpasswd. then i added username/password into .htpasswd file in form of username:password. that's what i did!!!

Comment: The password is encrypted, and htpasswd does it for you. Again, try putting into the file this `guest:6PTEFhrxg2idA` and see if guest-guest will work.

Comment: I did save guest:6PTEFhrxg2idA in .htpasswd file. and entered guest as username && 6PTEFhrxg2idA as password, but it did not work!!!

Comment: Password is guest too, 6PTEFhrxg2idA is the password "guest" encrypted by htpasswd (in the file you must put the encrypted version). The file format is not username:password but username:encrypted_password

Comment: guest:6PTEFhrxg2idA is what i have in .htpasswd file. then when the logon window pops up, in username field,i entered guest and in password field, i entered 6PTEFhrxg2idA as password??? am i wrong?

Comment: Yes you're wrong, in the login you should type guest as password too. 6PTEFhrxg2idA equals to guest in htpasswd-encrypted format. In the .htpasswd file you must put only encrypted passwords, but in the login you must put the unencrypted one.

Comment: Oh, i see. what about the username? what's the username and where should i save it? should be saved in .htpasswd file too?

Comment: The first plain "guest" is the username, the other thing is the encrypted password. similarily, in `username:o41IzhKcgWh2g`, "username" is the username, and "password" is the password. You can generate them with the command line tool "htpasswd" or with [this site](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/). The site uses another encryption method (MD5) but it still works.

Comment: so where should i save the username? is it on the .htpasswd? in the form of username:password???

Comment: Go to [this site](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) and enter username & password, and it will give you the line ready to copy-paste in the .htpasswd file. The username IS the part before the **:**, but the password (after it) isn't in clear text. The format is username:encrypted_password. [Here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/htpasswd/) is a full explaination of the file format.

Comment: Believe me, that's exactly what i did!!something is wrong but i don't know what it is. I have everything but i don't know what's the problem???

Comment: If you trust me, send me the list of usernames & passwords via email (lord dot spectre at hotmail dot it) and I'll make you the htpasswd file. If you want, send me your file and I'll check if it's correct.